# Transform data to use lubridate on it

Tags: r, character, numeric, lubridate

First thanks for all of your answer to other posts, it helped me a lot. 
There is my first one.

I have that kind of data :

```
 [1] 1986.05 1986.06 1986.07 1986.08 1986.09 1986.10 1986.11 1986.12 1987.01 1987.02 1987.03 1987.04 1987.05 1987.06
```

I would like to transform it to

```
 [1] 1986-05 1986-06 1986-07 1986-08 1986-09 1986-10 1986-11 1986-12 1987-01 1987-02 1987-03 1987-04 1987-05 1987-06
```

I tried to use `gsub()` , or to paste `my data + "-01'`, but here is the problem : it transform my data in character one : `1986.10` become `1986-1`.

It's supposed to be a month so .10 is different to .1.

I can't really explain how I manage to be in tat situation, but now I really want to know how to transform this directly from R ! (Would have been easier on Excel)

Thanks !

---

EDIT :

I'm Editting my post to give details about the problem.

THE problem is that most of method transform the column from numeric to character.

The result is that 1986.10 [October 1986] become 1986.1 [January 1986]. It's seems that a character value can't have a "0" at the end. But it's important to keep it...

Comment: Why do you have a SAS tag here? I can provide a SAS solution, but you seem to be referencing R terminology.

Comment: How did you use `gsub`? I'm curious as to why this wouldn't have worked. Seeing what you've done that didn't work is helpful for debugging

Comment: @Reeza Hi ! Indeed, I did a mistake... Sorry, it's just about R
@camille Hi, i did this : `ET$Date <- gsub("[.]", "-", ET$Date)`

I will post an answer to speak in detail about the problem.

Comment: `R` cannot distinguish both `1986.10` and`1986.1` after reading as numeric unless you read as `character` from the file

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that it is the Year.month, there are multiple ways to do this.  Convert it to `yearmon` class (from `zoo`) and then change the `format`

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(as.character(v1), format = "%Y.%m"), "%Y-%m")  
#[1] "1986-05" "1986-06" "1986-07"
```

---

Or this can be done by replacing the `.` with `-` using `sub`

```
sub(".", "-", v1, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "1986-05" "1986-06" "1986-07"
```

---

If the value is numeric, and it won't be able to distinguish between `1986.1` and `1986.10`.  One option would be to read as character vector/column  ('v2') and then process it

```
format(as.yearmon(v2, format = "%Y.%m"), "%Y-%m")
#[1] "1986-01" "1986-10" "1986-05"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1986.05, 1986.06, 1986.07)
v2 <- scan(text = "1986.1,1986.10,1986.5", what = "", sep=",", quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hello ! 
Thanks for your answer, but it didn't slove my problem. I'm sorry if I can't explain clearly I'm not fluent in english. 

Both method don't works. Why ? Because it transform numeric data to character data. Why is it a problem ? Because 1986.10 [October 1986] become 1986-1 [January 1986]. 
If the data become character, the "0" at the end disappear !
That's THE problem !

Comment: @RandomSpiRiT  How do you distingish `1986.10` and `1986.1` if both are numeric values? The `R` reads both as same unless you pre-process it

Comment: @RandomSpiRiT  If you have `1986.1` for January formatted as `1986.01` then it is a different matter, can be solved easily

Comment: thanks for your answers. 
I guess I miss some knowledge... 

I've tried many more things. So my column wich have values like `1986.09, 1986.10, 1986.11, 1986.12, 1986.01` is a `numeric (class)` & `double (typeof)` one.
And Indeed, after changing it to character, R consider both `1986.01` and `1986.1` as `January 1986`.
I'm not sure to understand your update. I've tried the 3rd idea, but it's the same problem. January and October became both January... 
I'm a beginner, sorry if I miss some basical informations.

Comment: @RandomSpiRiT  I would suggest to get the data read in character instead of reading it in numeric and then process

Comment: @RandomSpiRiT  That is easy.`sprintf('%.2f', c(26.1, 26.01))#
[1] "26.10" "26.01"`

Comment: It piss me off...
No worries, I will do it for sure at the end. 
I need to add the 0 after transforming the data as.character, your code works for numeric data right ? 
I tried : `sprintf('%.7s', ET$Date)` but it don't works : 
`[1] "1986-05" "1986-06" "1986-07" "1986-08" "1986-09" "1986-1"  "1986-11"`

I've already find an ugly way to slove my problem (cut the variable in 2 numeric, transform every 1 to 10, then paste it again with a `sep= "-"` , but I really WANT to find the best way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

```
data have;
format year_mon_decimal_number 7.2; 
input year_mon_decimal_number @@; datalines;
1986.05 1986.06 1986.07 1986.08 1986.09 1986.10 1986.11 1986.12 1987.01 1987.02 1987.03 1987.04 1987.05 1987.06
run;

data want;
  set have;
  date = input (put(year_mon_decimal_number*100,6.), yymmn6.); 
  format date yymmd7.;
run;
```